# UITableViewCell selectedBackgroundView customization

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a custom `selectedBackgroundView`. Is there a delegate method when the `selectedBackgroundView` shows? For example, if I press one cell and keep it pressed, the cell is highlighted and the `selectedBackgroundView` is showing. I want to change one of the cell's subviews when this happens.

I have tried using the gesture recognizer's delegate method `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer`, but this gets called too late. I want a to know the second it starts that selection animation. If this can't be done, is there a way to make the `selectedBackgroundView` be on top of all the cell's subviews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. You have to override `-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated` and perform the changes there. I also tried overriding the `touchesBegan` event, but doing this completely removes the cell's selection (doesn't get selected anymore).